# Nginx 'rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting' resulting in 500

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm having a bit of a problem with nginx 1.2.1-2.2 on Raspbian wheezy. I think it started after I changed the index thing in my sites-available/default file. Here are the relevant files:

```
nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

---

```
sites-available/default

server {
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /home/tom/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /yourls {
    # YOURLS time
    if (!-e $request_filename){
         rewrite ^(.*)$ /yourls-loader.php break;
    }
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        # With php5-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error when trying to access any WordPress page, including just typing local.dyn.kwl.me/wordpress/ into address bar or adding index.php or wp-admin to that URL. In the browser it displays as a 500, but the nginx logs say this:

```
2013/08/19 17:55:49 [error] 31600#0: *58 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/wordpress/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html", client: 109.149.13.53, server: localhost, request: "GET /wordpress HTTP/1.1", host: "local.dyn.kwl.me"
2013/08/19 17:55:49 [error] 31600#0: *59 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/favicon.ico/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html", client: 109.149.13.53, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "local.dyn.kwl.me"
```

I'd imagine something is wrong with index or try_files in my sites-default file. Can anyone see what?

Comment: What is location /yourls referring to? are you using domain.com/yourls to access your Wordpress site?

Comment: Why is there a try_files outside of a location block?

Comment: I am getting this error on a magento site too

Comment: @JoeBuckle That's irrelevant. WordPress is stored in /wordpress/.

Comment: @Danack My research suggested I should try adding that to fix the error I'm getting.

Comment: Where is this nginx logs ? I also have similar problem and favicon is showing from another website and your log mentions favicon so i want to check my logs too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I run WordPress sites on Nginx a lot. Here is a partial successful config of the location directives if you can make use of them. Nginx version is `1.0.15`. You might want to change the `fastcgi_pass` param to run whatever your fastcgi_wrapper is running on. Maybe `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000`

```
    location @php { 
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9090;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }  

    if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
            break;
    }
```

So, in your sites config

```
sites-available/default

server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /home/tom/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;


    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    ## Original Config
    # location ~ \.php$ {
    #    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        # With php5-cgi alone:
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
    #    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #    fastcgi_index index.php;
    #    include fastcgi_params;
    # }

    ## New Config
    location @php { ## Depending on your Nginx version, you might need to change this to location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9090; ## Maybe change to 9000 or use socket fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }

    ## Wordpress Rewrite
    if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
            break;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your last comment to me. If your DNS doesn't resolve to the sub directory /wordpress/ then you must change your rewrite rule.

```
    ## Wordpress Rewrite
    if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /wordpress/index.php?q=$1 last;
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Now WordPress (still none of my other directories have any problems) is wanting to download a file called 'download' containing the contents of index.php. I am so confused :/ I'm using the config you posted, with `location ~ \.php$` and using a socket instead of a local IP and port for php5-fpm.

Comment: It's trying to download the file because you're not passing the request to PHP so your fastcgi_pass configuration is probably wrong in my opinion. Try using this fastcgi_pass fastcgi_pass if it worked before `unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`

Comment: Well, both /yourls-next (php script) and /wordpress/wp-admin work properly. It's just /wordpress that instantly generates the download file. /wordpress/index.php takes a while, but then still asks me to download that file. I've tried disabling the WordPress rewrite rule, but that had no effect on anything. I might try reinstalling WordPress.  There's nothing in the config that is specifically targeting WordPress' front-end.

Comment: I don't believe it has anything to do with the WordPress installation. What are you using as a FastCGI wrapper? php-fpm I presume?

Comment: Yes, php5-fpm package from the debian repositories. I'll try reinstalling WordPress. I thought it might've been something to do with having maintenance mode on, but I've disabled that now and nothing has changed.

Comment: This is crazy and I'm really confused about what's happening. I put wordpress into a new directory called wordpress-test. It returned a 404. I commented out the rewrite rule. Now I'm getting a 500. I've genuinely got no idea what's going on. Would the debug log for nginx be any use?

Comment: The issue seems to have fixed itself after I got tired of it and gave myself a couple days' break. This probably fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused by the sample configuration. It seems you define a named location @php but I didn't find any reference to that internal location. Could you elaborate on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? (specific to Magento maybe)

```
server {
        listen 80 default;
        ssl off;
        root /var/www/magento;
        server_name mydomain.com.au;
        location / {
            index index.html index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
            expires 30d;
        }
        location ^~ /app/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /includes/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /lib/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /report/config.xml { deny all; }
        location ^~ /var/ { deny all; }
        location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
            auth_basic "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
            auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
            autoindex on;
        }
        location /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
            return 404;
        }
        location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
            rewrite / /index.php;
        }
        location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
            rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
        }
        location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
            if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
            expires off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
            fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }           
    }

server {
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain_com_au.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mydomain_com_au.key;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/crt/mydomain_com_au.crt;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.ssl.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.ssl.error.log;
        server_name mydomain.com.au;
        root /var/www/magento;
        location / {
            index index.html index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
            expires 30d;
        }
        location ^~ /app/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /includes/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /lib/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
        location ^~ /report/config.xml { deny all; }
        location ^~ /var/ { deny all; }
        location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
            auth_basic "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
            auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
            autoindex on;
        }
        location /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
            return 404;
        }
        location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
            rewrite / /index.php;
        }
        location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
            rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
        }
        location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
            if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
            expires off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
            fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }            
    }
```

HTH

Comment: Well, this worked, but only a little bit. Now I'm getting `2013/08/20 15:04:42 [error] 591#0: *6 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/favicon.ico", client: 109.149.13.53, server: local.dyn.kwl.me, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "local.dyn.kwl.me"`, so without all the index stuff, just the favicon.ico error.

Comment: When I had the same issue, I found out that I mistyped 1 character on my https root folder. Check for any typos.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
location / {
...   
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to give a brief explanation as to why this would help the asker.