# nginx - rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html"

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I cannot figure out why this error is happening: *"rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html""*

I found a **[similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321325/nginx-rewrite-or-internal-redirection-cycle-while-internally-redirecting-resul)** and tried various recommendations based on what I read, but to no avail.

Here is my nginx config.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/public;
    index index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name ourdomain.com;

    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # add the following line in for added security.
        try_files $uri =403;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay resolved.  The issue was the

```
location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php
}
```

Removed it and all is well again.

Comment: you need to add ";" at the end of this line: rewrite / /index.php

Answer (score 1):

This is better asked on Server Fault.

It looks like /index.html is matching `/index.php?$query_string`, which is being passed to php, and I'm guessing redirecting from there back to `/index.html`.

I can't really give you anymore information than that though since your question doesn't specify the request URL and I know nothing about possible redirects in your app.